# To use variable text in folium iframe

Tags: iframe

I know how to add text to Image which appear when I click the marker.

```
html = '''<h3> This is a big popup</h3><br>
<img src="data:image/JPG;base64,{}"><br>
<p>foo bar</p>'''.format
```

But how I can use the text variable?

Comment: 1) what language is that?  2) what are you trying to do?  3) what is your expected output.?  All I see here is some HTML assigned to a variable of *some sort* (no idea what language), with an extremely ambiguous problem stated.  Oh and something about an iFrame ..

Comment: I make map with folium in python. When I tap a marker Image appear. I want to add the variable text to this Image.